# Mac book doesn't boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, display

My Mac book pro 13.3 inch retina display August 2014, did not boot after a normal shut down. It gave sound on power on but after stays grey. I tried all options available on net <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but no success.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the set of Start up keys that you can try.

I would try the Safe mode first, followed by Apple Hardware Test.

If it does not boot in Safe mode and passes the Apple Hardware Test, use the OS X recovery "cmd+r" to restore your OS X installation.

[image: start up]

Comment: All done no response

Comment: Sorry to hear, sounds like your disk died. Then you are ready to bring it to Apple repair, it is still under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just command-v at startup? If it doesn't start up after that, check for any disk I/O Errors in the startup process. You will need to make sure you press that key combination straight after the boot chime.

If the machine doesn't boot at all, you may try to reset the SMC. The procedure for this depends on the Mac model you have, see this [Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201295) for details.

Comment: Earlier the chime sound was coming now that has stopped

Comment: It won't response to anything I think it's dead